How does SelectionContainer support long pressing to select all by default

                SelectionContainer {
                    Text(
                        text = valueText,
                        style = if (lowKey) MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium else MaterialTheme.typography.bodyLarge,
                        lineHeight = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium.lineHeight,
                        color = if (lowKey) MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurfaceVariant else MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground,
                        maxLines = 5,
                        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                    )
                }

The above code, if the text content is relatively long, such as 200 characters, I will only select a small portion of the text after long pressing. How to achieve default selection by long pressing?
kotlin = "2.0.0"
composeBom = "2024.04.01"
I hope there is a way to enable default selection of all text when long pressed.

Unrelated but you are using an outdated version of Compose. Current bom is 2024.12.01
